# not able to find file through jenkins pipeline even though the file exist on server

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We have a jenkins pipeline through which we are executing shell script.
Below command i need to executed which is throwing error.

```
build_date='2022-10-13'
ui_tag_value=`cat /data/lib/jenkins/workspace/ui_tag.properties | grep ${build_date}= | cut -d'=' -
f2`
```

ERROR :

```
cat: can't open '/data/lib/jenkins/workspace/ui_tag.properties': No such file or directory
```

Above command is present in sh file which we are executing through pipeline
File exist on the above path and also command works when used on the server but through jenkins pipeline we are facing issue. Any solution ?

I tried changing permission and paths but no luck. Need any ideas on how can this error be fixed ?

Comment: My first guess would be, that `/data` is not mounted on the jenkins server. Basically, I would check the path top-down, until which point the directories exist.

Comment: Is the Build running on a different Agent which doesn't have the file?

Comment: no its running on master and not on any slave...also i tried to give a different path but same error

Comment: Before cat command, list the file with 
We have a jenkins pipeline through which we are executing shell script. Below command i need to executed which is throwing error.

`ls -la /data/lib/jenkins/workspace/`. Share the results